# Error in using createEntityAdapter of Redux Toolkit in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am having a problem in utilizing the createEntityAdapter of ReduxToolkit
Error:
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Supplier Slice:
import { createSlice,createAsyncThunk,createEntityAdapter } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import axios from 'axios'

```
export const getSupplierData = createAsyncThunk(
    'supplier/getSupplierData', async () => {
        const response = axios.get(
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/supplier/"
        );
        const data = await (await response).data
        return data
    })

const suppliersAdapter = createEntityAdapter({})


export const { selectAll:selectSuppliers} = suppliersAdapter.getSelectors(
    state=>state.suppliers
)


export const supplierSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'supplier',
    initialState:suppliersAdapter.getInitialState({}),
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: {
        [getSupplierData.fulfilled]:(state,action)=>action.payload
    }
})


export default supplierSlice.reducer
```

supplier.js

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { getSupplierData,selectSuppliers} from './SupplierSlice'
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const classes = useStyles();
useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getSupplierData()) 
}, [])
const suppliers = useSelector(selectSuppliers)
console.log(suppliers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below:

```
export const getSupplierData = createAsyncThunk(
    'supplier/getSupplierData', async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/supplier/"
        );
        const data = await response.data;
        return data
});
```